# What is the best way to migrate all data from Oracle 11.2 to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: python, sql-server, oracle, data-migration

The approach I am trying is to write a dynamic script that would generate mirror tables as in Oracle with similar data types in SQL server. Then again, write a dynamic script to insert records to SQL server. The challenge I see is incompatible data types. Has anyone come across similar situation? I am a sql developer but I can learn python if someone can share their similar work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard" in SSMS?

i.e. if you create an empty SQL server database and right click on it in SSMS then one of the "tasks" menu options is "Import Data..." which starts up the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard". This builds a once-off SSIS package .. which can be saved if you want to re-use.

There is a data source option for "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle".

You might have a better Oracle OLE DB Provider available also to try.

The will require Oracle client software to be available.

I haven't actually tried this (Oracle to SQL*Server) so am not sure if reasonable or not.

How many tables, columns?

Oracle DB may also have Views, triggers, constraints, Indexes, Functions, Packages, sequence generators, synonyms.

Comment: I will try that but I need the script that populates each table too. I have around 22k tables and 3k views

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the views part, but the above method will create all the tables in the destination database and populate those tables with data given both servers can communicate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I used linked server, got all the metadata of the tables from dba_tab_columns in Oracle. Wrote script to create tables based on the metadata. I needed to use SSIS script task to save the create table script for source control. Then I wrote sql script to insert data from oracle, handled type differences through script.